# Как правильно написать: "Не содержит спирт" или "Не содержит спирта"?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно написать: "Не содержит спирт" или "Не содержит спирта"?

Answer (score 1):

Употребление родительного падежа в данном случае указывает  на значение полного отрицания. Винительный падеж уместно использовать, если подразумевается указание на какой-то определенный спирт (метиловый, этиловый...).

Answer (score 0):

Обв варианта одинаково возможны. 
Первый вариант выглядит более книжным.

Answer (score 0):

Если при глаголе есть отрицание, то существительное должно быть в родительном падеже.

Comment: Это не всегда верно.